# Якорь на веб-странице, в адресе которой содержится символ #

Tags: html, url

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добавить якорь на страницу, в адресе которой уже содержится символ `#`? Например, адрес: `http://nnn.mmm/#/MyPage`. Мне нужно добавить на данную страницу якорь `#yakor`, чтобы корректно отображалась ссылка `http://nnn.mmm/#/MyPage#yakor`.

Comment: в сами пробовали это сделать? если сделать ссылку <a href="#yakor">якорь </a> то у вас якорь сам поменяется на  #yakor

Comment: в случае  <a href="#yakor"> переход на главную страницу

Comment: А зачем Вам это надо?

Comment: Имеется таблица с n-м кол-вом записей, каждую из которых можно редактировать. форма для редактирования расположена вверху странице и создается только после нажатия на кнопку "ред", соответственно желателен переход на данную форму. Можно, конечно же, решить это новым модальным окном, но интересует вопрос с якорем

Comment: вы напишите как выглядит ваша ссылка

Comment: для чего # на ссылке?

Comment: Адрес тек. страницы http://dev.app/#/MyPage (локальная версия приложения).на странице MyPage на элемент  <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="vm.editMode" id="editPanel"> ч/з <a href="#editPanel"></a> - выполняется переход на главную страницу приложения http://dev.app/#/home

Comment: если вы используете ангуляр - смотрите `anchorScroll`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5c9kky2n/ Если подойдет - позже оформлю как ответ. Пока убежал по делам.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте вместо url типа(все, что после # распознается, как якорь):

```
http://nnn.mmm/#/MyPage.html#anchor
```

Если используете хеш как путь, используйте ниже приведенный url:

```
http://nnn.mmm/%23/MyPage.html#anchor
```